# How to take down APK when serving both a bundle and an APK

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-bundle

I have the following scenario. There's an old APK of the app that's on production along with the most recent version of the app in a Android Bundle format. It looks like there are no active devices using the APK which is good, but how can I totally deactivate that APK ?

[image]

Comment: I just sent an email to Play Console support and waiting for their reply. If I ever forget to post their reply here, please ping me.

Answer (score 0):

Next time you're publishing to Production, you should deactivate the APK. Not just publish the new version. The APK will still be served to users whose devices are compatible with the release.